# Change TextView on multiple parts of XML layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I am adding multiple XML `View`s programmatically. I'm using a layout inflater to add them and there are no problems with that.

But I'm not able to modify the `TextView` in each of them.

For example, consider I am adding a `LinearLayout` three times in my final `View`. I have a `TextView` in that linear layout. I extract it using `findViewById` and if I `setText("hello");` it is being reflected in the first layout, but not the second and third.

Will the inflater create new ids dynamically when adding multiple XML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part of your question, no: Ids are not dynamically generated by `LayoutInflater`.

When you say you are adding the views, where are you adding them? You mention a final View.

You don't include your code, but I assume you are calling `Activity.findViewById`. If you call `this.findViewById` from your `Activity`, you are traversing the entire View hierarchy and finding the first view with such an Id.

What you need to do, is iterate through all of the `LinearLayout`s that contain your `TextView`s and call `findViewById` on each of them.

```
for (LinearLayout layout : <fill in>) {
    ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.yourid)).setText("hello");
}
```

---

As for the `<fill in>`. Hard to tell how to fill it in without your code. It seems like you are adding these into a parent view right? Let's assume we have a parent `View parent = some view;`.

You just have to get all of its children and iterate. There are a few ways you can do it depending on which subclass of View the parent is. Let's keep it simple and assuming the parent is just another `LinearLayout`.

In that case the for loop changes to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) parent.getChildAt(i);
    ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.yourid)).setText("hello");
}
```

Comment: Hi Yarian, this is what i was looking for, thanks for the reply, but in for (LinearLayout layout : <fill in>) {
    ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.yourid)).setText("hello");
}what shoule be the fill in?? can you please give an example

Comment: @bharath See updated answer. You should really post your code next time.